# Insert pdf, add margin

Tags: pdftex, margins, pdfpages

I'd like to add to a pdf a margin of 1cm. Around this page I will add a frame later and like to draw something else to the frame. However, how can I add a margin to a pdf without scaling the pdf (-> single page document: the old pdf unscaled plus a 1 cm border)?

This is what I have tried it so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[frame, fitpaper]{incl.pdf}
% I thought I'd use fitpaper and add a margin...
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=1cm} % This does not do anything at all.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So `incl.pdf` is a single page document? Your idea is to insert the page, but make it have a `1cm` border *inside* the PDF page? I don't understand your final call to `\newgeometry`...

Comment: Add a margin without scaling! ... What a magic! Then, you have to crop.

Comment: It is a single page document. Hm..I want to have the pdf unscaled and outside a 1cm border.@AboAmmar: Cropping is to remove the border, isn't it?

Comment: @StefanBollmann: Will there be anything else in this document, or just the included page `incl.pdf`?

Comment: @Werner Later I'd like to draw a dashed frame around the edge of the whole construct. However, I thought to brake this problem into pieces...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following minimal example creates `lipsum.pdf` - a single-page document with an image (no border included):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

The following minimal example insert the single-page PDF `lipsum.pdf` with a 1cm padded border:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
% Grab external image for processing
\newsavebox{\externalimage}
\savebox{\externalimage}{\includegraphics{lipsum.pdf}}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1cm}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=\dimexpr\wd\externalimage+2\fboxrule+2\fboxsep,
  paperheight=\dimexpr\ht\externalimage+2\fboxrule+2\fboxsep,
  margin=0pt
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% (remove)
  \fbox{% (remove)
    \usebox{\externalimage}%
  }% (remove)
}
\end{document}
```

The included PDF remains unscaled as the page geometry is made to fix exactly `lipsum.pdf` + two rules (left/right or top/bottom, resulting from `\fboxrule`) + two 1cm gaps (`\fboxsep`).

For visual effect, I've added a frame around the included page, by that can be `(remove)`d.

Comment: Is there a way to do this leaving a 1cm margin only on one side, to the left? What I'm looking for is to get more place to bind with glue on a small a6 book. And the 130 pages pdf is already set.

Comment: @nilon: You can set the geometry with using `left` and `right` to set the respective left/right margins. Or, perhaps `margin=5mm,left=1cm` would set all margins to `5mm` but keep the left one at `1cm`. Alternatively, if you are printing double-sided, you might be interested in `inner` and `outer`. Read the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

Comment: @nilon: ...I see you've [asked a new/follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311721/5764). Good!

Comment: double thanks @Werner, for answer and the additional encouraging. However this isn't working for me. I've set watermarks, and images and poetry already set. I'd like not to mess up the pdf as is. Just _add_ margin without changing the rest of the pdf result. Possible perhaps?